# Issues with react and react-dom dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am starting to learn ReactJS. I have node installed on my computer. I am writing a basic "Hello World" Programming to see if my setup is alright.

The package.json file is:

```
  {
  "name": "part1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

The Javascript and HTML files are as follows-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Part1</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">


    </div>
    <script src="index.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<h1>"Hello world"</h1>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

However when i run this on the html file on the browser I get an error in the console as:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
and no output is displayed.
I am using VSCode and when i run the script using inbuilt run, i get an error that states that To run ES add type:module in package.json which i understand since the inbuilt run probably runs on node but why is this issue there on the browser and live server also?
Is this a setup issue or a semantic issue or any other technical issue. How do I resolve this?

When I am running using npm start the following is the error log-

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13)
5 verbose cwd /Users/pk/Desktop/Learning-react/part1
6 verbose Darwin 19.3.0
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v12.18.3
9 verbose npm  v6.14.6
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: try do add ```"start": "react-scripts start"``` inside scripts in package.json and run npm start

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to change your `index.html` file like this:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

And everything should work.

Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-1qq40?file=/index.js) example.

Comment: It didnt work mate,  this is a strange one since the required dependencies seem to be displayed as can be seen in the package.json file

Comment: Have you looked the example on codesandbox? index.js and index.html?

Comment: I did as I understand it now it seems to be dependencies issue more than a code issue

Comment: added the error log for more clarity on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Sorry one question: what did you use to create this app? create-react-app?

Comment: Nope I am trying to learn so I installed the dependencies as per requirement. I uses npm init-y followed by npm install react react-dom